# When insert()ing into a std::map why is the copy-contructor called twice?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, copy-constructor, stdmap

Why is the copy-constructor called twice in this code?

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class C {
private:
  int i_;
  char c_;

public:
  C(int i, char c) : i_(i), c_(c) { cout << "ctor" << endl; }
  C(const C& other) { cout << "copy-ctor" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  map<string, C> m;

  m.insert({"hello", C(42, 'c')});

  return 0;
}
```

Build & output:

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ctor
copy-ctor
copy-ctor
```

Comment: Note that if using recent versions of the c++ standard library you could use map::emplace and avoid the extra copy.

Comment: Your map insert is a three-step process: create value type of map -> copy to std::map::insert function local -> copy to the map, at right position of the tree. This whole can be avoided by `std::map::emplace` with piecewise_construct: `m.emplace( std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple("hello"), std::forward_as_tuple(42, 'c') );` construct the entry in right place .

Comment: To get a better picture of what is happening, you should output the value of `this`, instead of just a simple message:  `cout << "ctor: " << this << endl;` -- `cout << "copy-ctor " << this << endl;` -- This way, you can see the objects that are being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map value type is `std::pair<const int, C>`. `C` is not movable, thus `std::pair<const int, C>` is not movable.

`m.insert({"hello", C(42, 'c')});` Creates `C` and copies it to a `pair`, local variable `value` in `insert`, then copies a `pair` to a map bucket.

`m.emplace("hello", C(42, 'c'));` will copy `C` only once to a bucket.

```
Compiler options...
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
ctor
copy-ctor
```

Comment: There won't be any copy at all if the emplace use correctly: `m.emplace( std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple("hello"), std::forward_as_tuple(42, 'c') );`  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P6MEfjnsf

Comment: @JeJo Yes, I saw your great comment to the question, but I don't have time to explain it to the OP.